# trouble with binary search recursion

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm junior in C language and algorithms.

I try to use recursion for binary search and I can't understand how to check if number doesn't exist in array.

Here my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 15
#define midpoint(start, end) (start + end) / 2

void fill_array(int array[]);

int find(int target, int array[], int start, int end);

int main() {
    int array[SIZE];

    fill_array(array);
    return find(2, array, 0, SIZE);
}

void fill_array(int array[]) { //here I just fill array 
    for (int i = 0, number = 0; i <= SIZE; ++i) {
        array[i] = number++;
        number++;
    }
}

int find(int target, int array[], int start, int end) {
    int mid;
    mid = midpoint(start, end);

    if (target > array[mid]) {  
        find(target, array, mid + 1, end);
    }

    if (target < array[mid]) {
        find(target, array, start, mid - 1);
    }

    if (target == array[mid]) {
        printf("%d\n", mid);
    }
}
```

I want to return (-1) if number doesn't exist in array.

Comment: "*I want to return (-1) ...*" but `find()`  misses any `return` statement.

Comment: `i <= SIZE` --> `i < SIZE`

Comment: Recursion termination condition is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your code:

- Defining `midpoint()` as a macro is error prone. Your definition is not properly parenthesized, it should read:

  ```
  #define midpoint(start, end) (((start) + (end)) / 2)
  ```

  Written as half the sum, it actually would invoke undefined behavior for large values of `start` and `end`, a much safer version would be `start + (end - start) / 2`, but should not be used in a macro as it evaluates `start` twice.  Just write the code in the function directly.
- Your initialization function iterates one step too far, the loop should read:

  ```
  for (int i = 0, number = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      array[i] = number;
      number += 2;
  }
  ```
- `find()` should indeed return the index of the value found or `-1` if not found. You do not return anything.  make it return `-1` upon failure and the value of the recursive call when recursing.
- the arguments to `find` are `start`, the starting index of the range, included in the search, and `end` the upper bound, excluded from the search. You should not pass `mid - 1` when recursing on the left part.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 15

void fill_array(int array[], int size) {
    // here I just fill array with even numbers
    for (int i = 0, number = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        array[i] = number;
        number += 2;
    }
}

int find(int target, const int array[], int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end) {
        // empty range: not found
        return -1;
    }

    int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

    if (target == array[mid]) {
        return mid;
    }
    if (target > array[mid]) {  
        return find(target, array, mid + 1, end);
    } else {
        return find(target, array, start, mid);
    }
}

void locate(int value, const int array[], int size) {
    int res = find(value, array, 0, size);
    if (res < 0) {
        printf("%d was not found in the array\n", value);
    } else {
        printf("%d was found at offset %d\n", value, res);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int array[SIZE];

    fill_array(array, SIZE);
    locate(1, array, SIZE);
    locate(2, array, SIZE);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 was not found in the array
2 was found at offset 1
```

Note that `find()` can be implemented as a loop with less code:

```
int find(int target, const int array[], int start, int end) {
    while (start < end) {
        int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;

        if (target == array[mid]) {
            return mid;
        }
        if (target > array[mid]) {  
            start = mid + 1;
        } else {
            end = mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a BinarySearch C code for you to inspect and see where is your problem. 
    This part: `int BinarySearch` is doing BinarySearch via loops, 
    This part: `int BinarySearchRec` is doing BinarySearch via recursion.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int BinarySearch(int*,int,int);
int BinarySearchRec(int*,int,int,int);
int main(void){
    int length;
    int searchElement;
    int* list;
    printf("Enter the length of the list\n");
    scanf("%d",&length);
    list = malloc(length*sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter the search element for this list");
    scanf("%d",&searchElement);
    printf("Enter the elements for this list\n");
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
        scanf("%d",list+i);
    }
    int result1 = BinarySearch(list,length,searchElement);
    int result2 = BinarySearchRec(list,0,length-1,searchElement);
    printf("Result from loopy BinarySearch : %d\n",result1);
    printf("Result from recursive BinarySearch: %d\n",result2);
    return 0;
}

int BinarySearch(int* list, int length, int searchElement){
    int found=0;
    int min = 0;
    int max = length-1;
    int mid=0;
    while(found != 1 && max > min){
        mid = (max+min)/2;
        if(searchElement == list[mid]){
            found = 1;
        }else if(searchElement > list[mid]){
            min = mid+1;
        }else if(searchElement < list[mid]){
            max = mid;
        }

    }
    if(max > min){
        return mid;
    } else{
        return -1;
    }
}

int BinarySearchRec(int* list,int min,int max,int searchElement){
    int mid = (min+max)/2;
    if(max > min){
        if(searchElement == list[mid]){
                    return mid;
            }else{
                    if(searchElement < list[mid]){
                             return BinarySearchRec(list,min,mid,searchElement);
                    }else if(searchElement > list[mid]){
                            min = mid+1;
                            return BinarySearchRec(list,mid+1,max,searchElement);
                    }
            }
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This `list = malloc(length* ...; ...; for(... i<length;... list+i);` doesn't look good.